# Is there a way to get Excel to gather average from formulated weekdays or weekends?

Tags: excel, calendar, average, weekday

I have been given a project at work and I'm trying to figure out the average/utilization of teams from a number of different sections. I would like to try to have process as automated as possible so I'm trying to figure out how to get Excel to find the average of teams for weekdays and weekends separately. I've got the calendar mostly figured out, but I need some help with the last part. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2oshARUNgiGX1ViOHFaZHprejA/view?usp=sharing) is the link to the file. (I hope it's still an Excel file) I need the formula to relegated to a single cell and have the ability to ignore empty cells. [Here is a screenshot of what I've currently put together.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbceJ.png) Please note that I have AH4 selected to show the current (manual) formula I'm using. If anyone has any questions, please don't hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you got the `1.00` in AH4. My result was `1.142857143`.

You are going to need an **array formula¹** to accomplish determining the DOW with the [WEEKDAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Weekday-Function-05D360D7-2C3F-4691-9448-C96EA0351940) before feeding the appropriate values into the [AVERAGE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGE-function-047BAC88-D466-426C-A32B-8F33EB960CF6).

The array formula in AH4 is,

```
=AVERAGE(IF(WEEKDAY($B$3:INDEX($B$3:$AF$3, 1, MATCH(1E+99, $B$3:$AF$3)), 2)<6, $B4:INDEX($B4:$AF4, 1, MATCH(1E+99, $B$3:$AF$3))))
```

The array formula in AK4 is,

```
=AVERAGE(IF(WEEKDAY($B$3:INDEX($B$3:$AF$3, 1, MATCH(1E+99, $B$3:$AF$3)), 2)>5, $B4:INDEX($B4:$AF4, 1, MATCH(1E+99, $B$3:$AF$3))))
```

That sample workbook is currently available on my OneDrive [here](http://1drv.ms/1LZ1LmH).

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't quite work out. The formula you provided is looking at the entire month instead of just the weekdays. I got the '1.00' by manually looking at all the weekdays (minus holidays and days off) and then telling AH4 to Average them. the Average function automatically ignored any blank cells. This is also how I got the '2.00' in AK4, just with the weekends (and holidays and days off) manually selected instead. I'm trying to get Excel automatically do all this so I don't have to constantly change what cells the formula is looking at.